# Export data from JIRA into Excel dynamically

Tags: excel, jira, jira-plugin

I am using JIRA and in each sprint i do some steps to export file from JIRA and copy-paste it in Excel, and then apply my functions on it. This takes me a lot of time so i would like to automate all this steps using Excel. 
So, is it possible to export  data from JIRA into Excel dynamically ? 
Is there a way to do that please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can export search results directly to Excel: navigate to `Issues -> Search for Issues`, and run you search. After that you can click on `Export -> Excel (All/Current fields)`.
If this option is not available for you, you can export same search results to CSV file and Excel should be able to import it.

Please, refer to [official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/exporting-search-results-to-microsoft-excel-720416693.html) for more details.
If that is not what you are searching for, please specify your requirements more precisely.

Comment: I think "dynamically" in the question means by script. See your solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173930/wget-to-download-excel-from-jira-automatically

Answer (score 0):

See related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911414/2043349). You can export a filter to a csv file with a curl command. You can call this command via Shell in VBA. Then postprocess the output file with vba to integrate the data in your final report file.