# Wget to download excel from Jira automatically

Tags: jira, wget

I have tried the below commands to get the excel file automatically from jira but I'm getting different data other than the filter data.

wget --user username--password pass -O test.xls --ignore-length=on  http://esjirq62.emea.nsn-net.net:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/70920/SearchRequest-70920.xls?tempMax=1000;

curl -D my-output.xml -u upgrade:hjjKl801 -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://esjirq62.emea.nsn-net.net:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/70920/SearchRequest-70920.xls?tempMax=1000

Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set correct encoding header **gzip** :

```
curl -D my-output.xml -u upgrade:secret -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" "http://esjirq62.emea.nsn-net.net:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/70920/SearchRequest-70920.xls?tempMax=1000"
```

Some notes:

- Remove password from your example
- **-D** flag for curl dumps headers, not output. Did you mean **-o** maybe?
- *Content-Type* header can be skipped
- To be on the safe side, put the url in double quotes
- You can [copy request](https://lornajane.net/posts/2013/chrome-feature-copy-as-curl) from Google Chrome using developer tools

Comment: Many thanks @grundic :-). I finally got the export work with curl. (wget brings me a permission denied error; maybe because of SSO?). I like to save the output to a csv file that I can then open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get Wget work in my environment (permission denied error; maybe because of SSO?) but following curl command .

```
"D:\DSUsers\uid41890\Tools\curl.exe" -o C:\Users\uid41890\Documents\JIRA\search.csv -u uid41890:password -X GET "http://jiraurl:port/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-csv-current-fields/17899/SearchRequest-17899.csv"
```

No need for Header options as mentioned in @grundic's answer.

Replace -D by -o  in your original command and change the output file format from xml to csv for example.

Answer (score 0):

You must use -O flag as:

```
curl -o excel.xls -O -u upgrade:hjjKl801 -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://esjirq62.emea.nsn-net.net:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/70920/SearchRequest-70920.xls?tempMax=1000
```